# SQL Server - Mondays date based on week number and year (view)

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. I have a table that specifies the current year (done in C#) `Years.Year`
2. I have a table called Weeks which contains the numbers (1-53)  `Weeks.WeekNumber` http://whatweekisit.org/

Now from this I want to create a view which will list Monday's date of each week based upon the parameters `Years.Year` and `Weeks.WeekNumber`

the code below gets the week number but doenst calculate the date correctly:

```
SET DATEFIRST 4     
DECLARE @d DATETIME

SET @d = GETDATE() 
--BELOW IS WHAT I WANT TO WORK ALTHOUGH THE SUB QUERY RETURNS MORE THAN ONE VALUE
--(SELECT Weeks.WeekNumber FROM Weeks)

SELECT
  Weeks.WeekNumber,
  DATEADD(dd, (@@DATEFIRST + 5 + DATEPART(dw, @d)) % 7, @d) Monday
  FROM Weeks
```

Example data:

```
Week Number       Date
     1        29/12/2014
     2        05/01/2015
     3        12/01/2015
     4        19/01/2015
     5        26/01/2015
    ...           ...
    53        28/12/2015
```

**to Summarize:**

the year 2015 contains 53 Mondays, so I am trying to generate a SELECT statement which will specify the week number, and the date for each week, just like the Example data above

thanks for the help below, and the variety along with the suggestion of Calendar tables.... I will try and test all :)

Comment: yes sorry, will re-word

Comment: what's your problem ?

Comment: You're trying to determine what is the date of Monday for each of the ISO week numbers?

Comment: Consider building yourself a [calendar table](http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql), then your query becomes very simple indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, this is much easier if your build yourself a [calendar table](http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql), your query would simply be:

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2015;
SELECT  Date, ISOWeek
FROM    CalendarTable
WHERE   DayNumberOfWeek = 1
AND     ISOYear = @Year;
```

I will assume though that this is not an option for you. The first step is to get the first day of the year, which is fairly simple:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0101' AS DATE)
```

Then you can get the monday of this week:

```
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, YearStart), 0)
```

Then you a set of numbers from 1 -53 to add your weeks:

```
SELECT  TOP(53) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id)
FROM sys.all_objects
```

Finally, you need to work out if the if the first day of the year falls in the first week of this year, or the last week of last year. If it is the latter then you need to add one week to your weekstart calculation. Combining the above you get:

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2016;
SELECT  n.Weeknumber,
        StartOfWeek = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, d.YearStart) + n.WeekNumber + n.Factor, 0)
FROM    (SELECT CAST(CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0101' AS DATE)) AS d (YearStart)
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP(53) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id),
                    CASE WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, d.YearStart) = 1 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END
            FROM sys.all_objects
        ) AS n (Weeknumber, Factor)
WHERE   DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, YearStart) + n.WeekNumber + n.Factor, 0)) = n.WeekNumber;
```

The where clause at the end will just remove the last week to ensure that for 52 week years you don't include the first week of the next year.

**EDIT**

Just realised you already have a table of 53 numbers, so you don't need to generate your own:

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2016;

SELECT  w.Weeknumber,
        StartOfWeek = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, d.YearStart) + w.WeekNumber + f.Factor, 0)
FROM    (SELECT CAST(CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0101' AS DATE)) AS d (YearStart)
        CROSS JOIN Weeks AS w
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, YearStart) = 1 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) f (Factor)
WHERE   DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, d.YearStart) + w.WeekNumber + f.Factor, 0)) = w.WeekNumber;
```

Comment: any ideas why I get 0 results when i use 2015?

Comment: Yes, I had missed off some of the where clause (which you kindly corrected), however the correction wasn't quite right, and was missing a part. It should work as expected now.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't use your lookup table but produces a table of dates for each Monday in the year (only lightly tested):

```
DECLARE @year INT = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())
DECLARE @firstDate DATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @year) + '0101'
SET DATEFIRST 1;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   1 AS WeekNo ,
                        DATEADD(DD, 1 - DATEPART(DW, @firstDate), @firstDate) AS MonDate
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   cte.WeekNo + 1 ,
                        DATEADD(DAY, 7, cte.MonDate) AS MonDate
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, 7, cte.MonDate)) = @year
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
```

It calculates the first Monday of the given year, then simply adds 7 days until the end of the year.

Answer (score 2):

you may try some thing like this

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME

SET @startDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
SET @endDate = '2016-1-31';

WITH dates(Date) AS 
(
    SELECT @startdate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d,7,[Date])
    FROM dates 
    WHERE DATE < @enddate
)

SELECT Date
FROM dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write as:

```
-- SET DATEFIRST to U.S. English default value of 7.
SET DATEFIRST 7;

SELECT DATEPART( wk, [DateofYear]) as [Week Number],
      [DateofYear] as[MondayDate]
FROM (
 SELECT TOP (365)
 DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)-1, '20150101') AS [DateofYear]
 FROM [master].dbo.spt_values
 WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number
 ) AS T
 WHERE datepart(dw,[DateofYear]) = 2 --Monday
 ORDER BY [DateofYear];
```

Comment: this fetches the fridays for me

Comment: You can check your datefirst setting using `@@DATEFIRST` function and SET DATEFIRST to U.S. English default value of 7 as `SET DATEFIRST 7;`

Comment: year 2016 has 52 weeks but this function returns 53 weeks ?

Answer (score 2):

Kindly try this one also :-

```
Declare @StartDate Date = '2015-01-01'

---- here consider Your Week table as AllWeeks
;With AllWeeks As
(
    Select   1 As WeekNo

    Union All

    Select  (WeekNo + 1)
    From    AllWeeks As w
    Where   w.WeekNo < 53
)

Select   w.WeekNo
        ,Dateadd(Day, (2 - Datepart(DW, Dateadd(Week, w.WeekNo, @StartDate))), Dateadd(Week, w.WeekNo, @StartDate)) As Mondays
From    AllWeeks As w
Where   Datepart(Year, Dateadd(Day, (2 - Datepart(DW, Dateadd(Week, w.WeekNo, @StartDate))), Dateadd(Week, w.WeekNo, @StartDate))) = 2015
```

Comment: As this is the accepted answer just one hint; In my (german) system it delivers each tuesday...

Comment: You may right, I need to use ISO_Week, but I got an error in SQL Server 2008 while trying to use ISO_week.

Comment: for year 2016 it works, but for 2017 it miss first week :p

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
;WITH Recur AS
(
    SELECT CAST('1/1/' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME) AS RecurDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, RecurDate)
    FROM Recur
    WHERE YEAR(RecurDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
)
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, RecurDate, 103) AS [Date]
FROM
    Recur
WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,RecurDate) = 'Monday'
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
DECLARE @year INT=2015;

WITH ThreeHundredSixtySixNumbers AS
(
    SELECT TOP 366 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) As nmbr
    FROM sys.objects --any large table with at least 366 rows
)
,FirstDayOfYear AS
(
    SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),@year) + '/1/1'  AS DATE) AS FirstDay
)
,MondayOnly AS
(
    SELECT nmbr AS DayIndex
    FROM ThreeHundredSixtySixNumbers
    WHERE ((nmbr - DATEPART(WEEKDAY,(SELECT FirstDay FROM FirstDayOfYear)))%7) = 0
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DayIndex) AS WeekNumber
      ,DATEADD(DAY,DayIndex,(SELECT FirstDay FROM FirstDayOfYear))
FROM MondayOnly
```

Comment: are you sure with your given answer ?

Comment: nearly, however this returns the Friday of each week, ill see if I can change it

Comment: it returns only 12 weeks to me, it ends with March ?! (for 2016)

Comment: @Muflix, I was lazy and did not use a proper approach for the Numbers table. Might be, that `sys.objects` is to short in your test DB ...